PyVoIP - SIP - write_sound function makes a lot of noise and has bad quality
I am using PyVoIP library to connect SIP server and making, answers calls.
I want to make an announcement sound if anyone calls me, so I am using write_sound function but it isn't working well.
def answer(call: VoIPCall):

    sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("announcement.wav")
    call.answer()
    call.write_audio(sound._data)

I used wave and pydub libraries but nothing changed.
It sounds perfect while I listen on computer but it sounds very bad while I call and listen.
I used ffmpeg, Audacity, Audition but nothing works.
My wav file is correctly formatted:
announcement.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, ITU G.711 mu-law, mono 8000 Hz

I tried to change some of options with ffmpeg but it didn't work either:
ffmpeg -i announcement.wav -ac 1 -ar 8000 -ab 64 -acoded pcm_mulaw -f wav ann2.wav

I have 1gbps internet connection, I also tried with Windows/Ubuntu/RHEL/MacOS and nothing changed.
Thanks.
